# Enable error logging to browser for flask under Apache + mod_wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

what are the exact steps i need to execute in order to enable error logging to browser so i don't check the error_log via console any more?

I'am using Flask under Apache + mod_wsgi.

If i place app.debug = True within my app it does not do anything.

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template, url_for

application = Flask(__name__)

app = application
app.config['TESTING'] = True
```

Comment: first show your code

Comment: i have added my code.

Comment: Can anybody help me send error output to the browser? Its really annoying logging via ssh and checking error_log with 'tail -f' each time.....